# Does Buddhism accept Existence?

Tags: texts, sutras, suttas

Does Buddhism accept Existence ?

If it does what is Existence?

Comment: I think this question is answered by [this answer](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/12750/254).

Comment: What does "accept" mean in this context, can you explain a little what you mean by "accept"?

Comment: Hi Theravada. Could you elaborate on *Question title and content*, to increase clarity? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Existence is commonly held to be that which objectively persists independent of one's presence.

(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existence)

When you light a flame based on certain chemical reactions there is a flame. Likewise based on Dependent Origination (DO) there is a being (Satta). This being neither exists in the sense that it is a static everlasting entity, nor a completely materialistic entity. What exists is - like the chemical reaction in the flame - a being as combusting collection of fabrication conditioned by DO. Hence, on the view that one persists as existence, we do not exist and in the sense of materialism after breakup the being is no more, then as the process of DO is at work, thus we cannot say we do or don't exist.

Another angle to look at it is that a being is purely mental construction or something we perceive. What every attributed with associated with this concept in reality what exists will differ. Hence there is not existance of a being as we would think or expect it to be, but what is there is a dancing collection aggregates, just like a fire in the wind. As our sense doors contact with their respective object fabrication are created different direction like a flame dancing when in contact with the wind.

Comment: Thank you Suminda, Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Added some more descriptions.